# Problem adding custom backoffice extension dependency to another (facade) extension

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

So, my extensioninfo.xml file looks like this:

```
<extension abstractclassprefix="Generated" classprefix="TrainingFacades" name="trainingfacades">

    <!-- you should add all required extensions to this list, except platform 
        extensions which are automatically required -->
    <requires-extension name="acceleratorfacades"/>
    <requires-extension name="trainingcore"/>
    <requires-extension name="trainingbackoffice"/>

    <coremodule generated="true" manager="de.hybris.platform.jalo.extension.GenericManager" packageroot="com.training.facades"/>


    <meta key="backoffice-module" value="true"/>
</extension>
```

The reason for why this is happening, is in my custom backoffice extension, services are located under backoffice/src, not under src.

But as I need loginInfoHandler from backoffice context, I need them placed exactly there. Or maybe I can add jar with loginInfoHandler to another extension (how can this be done)?

I'd appreciate your help, for sure.

Comment: Why is your service depending on loginInfoHandler? Can you share some code? This class will most likely not be accessible in facades extension. So how are you planning on using your service in facades extension?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your scenario; it's not described clearly. But if my understanding is correct, you have a custom backoffice service which needs to pass loginInfoHandler data to a facade/service in another extension. Is it correct?

If my understanding is correct, you just need to make your custom backoffice extension depend on the facade (i.e. the custom backoffice extension has a requires-extension to the facade extension). Then, you can inject this facade to your backoffice service. You pass whatever data you need from loginInfoHandler to the facade. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is incorrect. `Backoffice` is the ultimate child extension and resides on the presentation layer. `Backoffice` should call `facades`, not the other way round. Same applies to other modules on the presentation layer eg. `storefront`, `occ`, etc.

[image]